# Why did spybot open overnight when I did nothing on my computer?

Tags: windows-7, spyware

This morning I woke up to find that spybot had opened on my computer and was ready to run. I did nothing to cause this to happen. I have one computer in the house. It has Windows 7. No network. I have a FIOS internet connection. I haven't opened any unknown email attachments and am very careful about this. I have Norton security suite that updates and scans daily. I have a longstanding alert (a windows 7 generated alert) that pops up a window monthly telling me to run spybot, but that window wasn't open and isn't connected to spybot. I closed the spybot application and everything is running fine currently. What happened? Is this spyware?

Comment: Perhaps you scheduled a scan with Spybot?

Comment: Maybe the NSA forgot to close the window :)

Comment: I don't think that malware would open a malware-hunting program at night... Sounds like scheduled scan.